# get list connected bluetooth headset in ios with react native

Tags: ios, bluetooth, react-native, headset

I want to develop an ios app with react native. I need to write a function in a module that return a list of bluetooth headset connected at the moment.
the problem is that I do not know how to do. I read about AVAudioSession but do not know how to exploit it. someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend bluetooth serial, it is currently the most up to date bluetooth connection library and provides the functionality you are looking for:
https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial

Comment: I already modify the module for android because some features were wrong. For example isConnected() function. Finally the module returns a list of devices that have been paired not connected.

Comment: I was under the impression that list() would provide a full list and isConnected() would be used to check for current connections.